# Unindent selected lines in gedit

Tags: keyboard, gedit

I'm using the Gedit text editor.

For a single line, we can simply press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to remove the indentation on that particular line.

How can I select several lines and unindent them all?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can remove the tab space from multiple lines by selecting those lines and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> is used to give a reverse tab, i.e. <kbd>tab</kbd> in the opposite direction, so this should work almost wherever you want to reverse tab.

Comment: +1 just to add that this also works in case you had set indents to be represented by spaces rather than tabs.

Comment: You can also use <kbd>tab</kbd> to indent multiple lines with spaces (instead of tabs) -- if you enable the option to "Insert spaces instead of tabs".  Kind of kludgy, but occasionally useful.